# How to concatenate string with having single ,double quaotes or special characters in php?

Tags: php, concatenation, string-concatenation

> I am having one onclick event with some paramters with it. But in some
> cases i am getting double quaotes or space between strings. so getting
> error of `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` or
> `invalid token`.
>
> How to overcome with this issue. I tried to use array and trim the
> variables but it wont work for me.

```
$stringArray = ['string 1', 'string'2','001'];
$concatenated = trim(implode(',',$stringArray));
```

E.g: I am getting 3 string like :

```
 $data1 = 'surgery';
 $data2 = 'Cardio'c';
 $data3 = 'hopsital ab"cc';

<a id='changeState' onclick=editModal(\"". $data1 ."\",\"". $data2 ."\",\"".$data3."\");>Click Here</a>
```

Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Where is your PHP code that generates this html line `<a id='changeState' onclick=editModal(` ... ? Without seeing that it will be impossible to debug it.

Comment: Just `json_encode()` each string that you are injecting into your inline javascript function paramters.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-do-i-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript#:~:text=Implementation%20is%20relatively%20straightforward%3A  Ultimately, I don't recommend your inline event listener anyhow.   Use `data-` attributes if you must, but pull all of your inline javascript out of your html and into an external script.

Comment: @GetSet function editModal(data1,data2,data3){    
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to change state of this attribute?")){
        $.ajax({  
            type:"POST",  
            url:"url",  
            dataType: "json",
            data:'data1=' + data1 + '&data2=' + data2 + '&data3=' + data3,  
            success: function(response){ 
                $('#msg').text(response.msg);
                    //success code
                        } 
                    }); 
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
 
}